# Java: Issue in SimpleDateFormat class

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a date string of format dd.MM.YYYY into date object as following:

```
String start_dt = "01.01.2011";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
System.out.print("Date is : "+date);
```

But I am getting this result `Date is : Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 MST 2010`
I tried it in different ides and even on [compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) , still same result.
So Am I doing anything wrong here, because its not suppose to behave like this. 
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern for year is incorrect.  You need to say:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct representation is `yyyy`

```
            String start_dt = "01.01.2011";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("Date is : "+date);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String start_dt = "01.01.2011";
         DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
         Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
         System.out.print("Date is : "+date);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should learn about DateFormat from here [link1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm) and [link2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you will realize that your code should be like that (year should be written in small letters).

```
String start_dt = "01.01.2011";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(start_dt);
System.out.print("Date is : "+date);
```